# jwt validation in backend springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

Im looking to create an angular application which login against a new authentication server created in springboot and return a jwt.

The idea is to create the application to be able to generate and sign the jwt token with a private key based on the user/password provided in the screen, the authentication server will validate the login information in database and generate the jwt token.

After that, a request will be sent to another microservice and in here I need to be able to validate the token, but this microservice wont be connected to the authentication service or database in any way, it will just validate the integrity of the token using a public key.

Im looking everywhere and I dont find the clue to be able to validate the token, I found this piece of code but for some reason when I execute the rest API exposed this code is not executed:

```
@Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();


        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.txt");
        String publicKey = null;

        try {
            publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }
```

Does what im trying to do makes any sense?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your auth server will will need to be the single issuer of JWTs to your microservices.  So, when a user logs in and successfully authenticates, your auth server will issue a JWT signed with a private key (signing MUST be asymmetric - RS256 is one example) you keep on the auth server only; do not give this private key to other microservices that you wish to validate JWTs inside of. What you can do is derive a public key based on the private key you sign your tokens with and publish that to an endpoint on your auth server that requires no authentication - the public key will be represented in the form of a JWK ([see link to spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517)). Google does something similar [here](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs).  Then, in each of your microservices, you will need to devise a way to make a GET request to the public key endpoint on your auth server every X minutes and cache the public key in each microservice.

Then whenever a request comes into one of your microservices, you grab the JWT, check its validity, and grant access/authorization if the token is valid.  The beauty of using a private/public key pair and asymmetric key signing is that you can validate a token based on the public key alone, but not sign it.  So as long as each service has the public key from your /cert endpoint, they can validate a token without ever needing to talk to the auth server or knowing the private key.

This will require a little more work up front, but will yield you massive amount of ease, flexibility, and peace of mind in the future knowing only one source knows your private key.

I suggest using [this library](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) to do JWT validation.

The overall architecture will end up looking something like this:
[image]